# Magento 2.4.5 performance issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, pagespeed, speedoptimization

Recently I've upgraded 2.3 to 2.4.5 and having following system configurations.

- php8.1
- MySQL 8
- Apache2.4 (Also tried with Nginx)
- Varnish configured

I have 16GB ram with 500Gn SSD and i5 processor ubuntu os.

My minified profile results are below.

```
magento - 10s
magento->routers_match - 6s
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:catalog_category_view - 6s
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:catalog_category_view->action_body - 6s
magento->LAYOUT - 9s
```

The 2.3 version magento loads overall page in 4 seconds where upgraded on takes 28secs and more.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance improving suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

- I think you can use Redis.
- Also see in the DB may be some queries takes more time.
- Also, use Magento's performance based
  configurations